# How do I match to a multiple of a n times in regex

Tags: python, regex, binary

I'm writing a python program to convert binary to hex and hex to binary (it's a learning exercise as much as anything), and in order to determine if the string that I'm passing to the function is in the correct format, I'm checking it against a regex.

I am currently trying to match anything of 4 bit binary format `10101010...`, so any 4 bits, n times. The regex I'm currently trying to use is

```
([01]{4})+
```

However, that's allowing strings through that aren't multiples of 4 in length. The 'entire' function is

```
def biToHex(biStr):
    biRegex = "([01]{4})+"
    if bool(re.match(biRegex, biStr)) == 0:
        return "BIN NOT FOUND"

    nibbles = [biStr[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(biStr), 4)]
    print nibbles
```

I'm aware that I currently can't deal with strings containing a space, but that's outside the scope of this question.

What regex can I use to match to the appropriate strings?

Comment: whats the aim of `bool(re.match(biRegex, biStr)) == 0` ?

Comment: @Kasra convert the output of `match` to a bool and check if it returns false? This is the 1st thing I'm writing in python, so I'm hacking it together, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are not anchoring your regex. If you added a `$` at the end, it would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
def biToHex(biStr):
    biRegex = "^([01]{4})+$"
    if bool(re.match(biRegex, biStr)) == 0:
        return "BIN NOT FOUND"

    nibbles = [biStr[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(biStr), 4)]
    print nibbles


print biToHex("010101011010")
```

Tried this.It is working.Added anchors.